# Express unknown error handler is logging custom errors

Tags: node.js, error-handling, express

I have a custom error handler in my express application. The configuration:

```
app.use(Routes.error);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
app.use(express.cookieParser(config.app.sessionSecret));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.session({
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000
    }
}));
app.use(flashify);
app.use(expressValidator);
app.use(app.router);
```

The error router:

```
error: function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error.jade', {
        error: err.message
    }, function(renderError, html) {
        if (renderError) {
            res.send(500, 'Error while displaying the error template!');
        } else {
            res.send(err.code, html);
        }
    });
},
```

The problem I have is that a custom error message is logged in the console:

```
//In the route
next(new NotFoundError('Could not find the template!'));

//Custom error
var NotFoundError = function(message) {
this.code = 404;
this.message = message;
};

util.inherits(NotFoundError, Error);
NotFoundError.name = 'NotFoundError';
```

This is very disturbing during the unit tests:

```
✔ server - testTemplateCreate
Error: Could not find the template!
✔ server - testTemplateEdit
```

It is correct that the template could not be found, but I do not want the message to be displayed. I thought, if you provide a custom error route, no native error function is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you install middleware matters.

You declare your error handler right at the top, which means that any middleware and routes following its declaration will *not* get handled by it. Instead, move your error handler to after the router:

```
...
app.use(app.router);
app.use(Routes.error);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I already read that the order matters and changed some parts of it, but did not think that you have to put the error routing behind the normaler router.